What is the correct translation of Bhagavad Gita chapter 9 verse 32?
I downloaded Bhagavad Gita from this website.

In chapter 9 verse 32, in the original Sanskrit text, there is "Striyo" word. However, in English translation, it's not the case, why? Is the English translation correct?
Second case, but related to first:
Even in this website, if we compare the word by word translation and the whole translation, it's different. For instance:

मां हि पार्थ व्यपाश्रित्य येऽपि स्यु: पापयोनय: |
स्त्रियो वैश्यास्तथा शूद्रास्तेऽपि यान्ति परां गतिम् || 32||
māṁ hi pārtha vyapāśhritya ye ’pi syuḥ pāpa-yonayaḥ striyo vaiśhyās
tathā śhūdrās te ’pi yānti parāṁ gatim


mām—in Me; hi—certainly; pārtha—Arjun, the son of Pritha;
vyapāśhritya—take refuge; ye—who; api—even; syuḥ—may be; pāpa
yonayaḥ—of low birth; striyaḥ—women; vaiśhyāḥ—mercantile people;
tathā—and; śhūdrāḥ—manual workers; te api—even they; yānti—go;
parām—the supreme; gatim—destination


Translation
BG 9.32: All those who take refuge in Me, whatever their birth, race, gender, or caste, even those whom society scorns, will attain the supreme destination.

Here's my chat with ChatGPT. I thought it would be better to include because this made more sense to me than above translation.
But I still want to know what is the exact English correct translation.

Please see this answer

Let's start with two separate translations then draw a contrast with other sects:
English Translation By Swami Gambirananda
9.32 For, O son of Prtha, even those who are born of sin-women, Vaisyas, as also Sudras [S.'s construction of this portion is: women, Vaisyas as also Sudras, and even others who are born of sin (i.e., those who are born low and are of vile deeds, viz Mlecchas, Pukkasas and others). M.S. also takes papa-yonayah (born of sin) as a separate phrase, and classifies women and others only as those darred from Vedic study, etc.-Tr.]-, even they reach the highest Goal by taking shelter under Me.
English Translation By Swami Sivananda
9.32 For, taking refuge in Me, they also who, O Arjuna, may be of a sinful birth women, Vaisyas as well as Sudras attain the Supreme Goal.
In the above two cases, both Scholars treated this as an adjective describing a noun. With 'Sinful' being the adjective and 'Women' being the Noun.
Now if we move across the board to Vaishnava Sect Gurus like Ramanujacharya:
English Translation of Ramanuja's Sanskrit Commentary By Swami Adidevananda
9.32 - 9.33 Women, Vaisyas and Sudras, and even those who are of sinful birth, can attain the supreme state by taking refuge in Me. How much more then the well-born Brahmanas and royal sages who are devoted to me! Therefore, roayl sage that you are, do worship Me, as you have come to this transient and joyless world stricken by the threefold afflictions. Sri Krsna now describes the nature of Bhakti:
In this case the adjective 'Sinful' is separated and disassociated with other Nouns.
English Translation By By Dr. S. Sankaranarayan
9.32. O son of Prtha, even those who are of sinful birth, [besides] women, men of working class, and the members of the fourth caste-even they, having taken refuge in Me, attain the highest goal.
This Scholar created a separation. He distinctly eliminated Sinful and all other Nouns (Women, men, Working call, Sudras ....)
English Translation by Shri Purohit Swami
9.32 For even the children of sinful parents, and those miscalled the weaker sex, and merchants, and labourers, if only they will make Me their refuge, they shall attain the Highest.
In this translation, the Scholar used Women as a general noun to represent both Parents (Man and Women).

Conclusion:
Most of the Scholars DID NOT GENERALIZE the entirety of Womenhood, or an entire Sex. So what to do? Simple, go the core. Ignore all translators who used word-to-word Sanskrit dictionary translation.
Who is the first to identify and extract Gita out of Mahabharata Itihasa and gave it its prominence by giving a commentary? It was Adi Shankara who first identified Gita from Itihasa and Various Upanishad from many Vedic Recessions and clubbed them together with Sutras to form a unique body of Sanatana Literature.
Understand the life of Sri Krishna, how he lived? How did he treat his mother, his gopikas, Draupathi, his Pathni, and then judge if Sri Krishna would categorize the entire women species as sinful or just women who have Sinned. Unless the other scholars are categorizing human birth as women itself being a result of prior lifetime Paapa. Also, Understand the life of Adi Shankara and to what lengths he went for his mother and how he would categorize this. One can look at their own Mothers to make a judgement.
